# Bugs de notificação

Tags: suporte, notificações

Existe uma notificação mas não sei a qual publicação pertence.Apenas aparece o número 1.

Ganhei 25 de reputação com algo,mas também não aparece,é normal?

Comment: Tem como postar uma captura de tela, ou a notificação já desapareceu?

Comment: Valores pequenos são notificados mas o detalhamento só aparece no perfil. Porém, não vejo nenhum +1 [no seu perfil](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11761/weslley-c-x-sardinha?tab=reputation). EDIT: parece que +1/-1 não é uma informação disponibilizada ao público...

Comment: Sumiu sim,depois que dei reload.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz um voto negativo em uma resposta, ela lhe custa `-1` de reputação. Se, por algum motivo, essa resposta (ou a pergunra a que pertence) for excluída no futuro você ganhará a reputação de volta: `+1`.

No entanto nenhuma publicação aparece na notificação porque, bem.. ela já foi excluída.

Isso também não aparece no seu perfil ou para nenhum outro utilizador porque não deve ser possível identificar quem fez um voto.

Comment: Não poderia existir uma notificação de "Uma pergunta de sua participação foi excluída" ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Poderia. Ficaria mais claro o que aconteceu na interface. Se quiser fazer um pedido de [`novo-recurso`](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/novo-recurso)